# Chart layout in PowerBI

Tags: charts, report, powerbi

I have multiple charts in PowerBI (Desktop).

I would like to group these charts together somehow so that when I move one a number of them move together.

I would like to do this to keep the layout of the report nice and neat as the number of charts increase.

```
Group 1:
Chart a    Chart b


Group 2:
Chart a    Chart b    Chart c
Chart d    Chart e
```

For example, with the above groups/charts, if I wanted to add another two charts to `Group 1` then I would need to shift each chart in `Group 2` down.  If I could instead move `Group 2` as a container then adding new charts to `Group 1` would be easy.

I don't see a way to do this in PowerBI.  I have looked into containers, into showing reports within reports.  This seems to be missing functionality, but I'm hoping there is a workaround?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment in PowerBI. 
You can select multiple graph by using CTRL+click on the graphs.